# Long Delay Adding Class Library Project to Existing Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have an existing solution that is several years old.  I have recently updated to Visual Studio 2015, and updated the projects in that solution to .NET 4.6.

When I try to add a new Class Library project to that solution:

- The Add New Project dialog hangs for about 2 minutes.
- The system tray displays a dialog "Microsoft Visual Studio is Busy".
- Once the dialog stops hanging, I select Class Library and give it a name and complete the process.

A coworker is experiencing the same issue.

What might cause Add New Project to hang for around 2 minutes, and how can that be solved?

Comment: Looks like similar issue had some possible solutions at following link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c5aaa761-1a73-440e-bf72-ce70047169d6/help-visual-studio-hangs-creating-new-projects?forum=vssetup